# JSF PrimeFaces dataTable changing value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have the following code:

```
<p:dataTable style="background-color:white;color: white;" var="url" value="#{data.data.requirementsDocuments}" editable="true" id="urlTable" editMode="cell">
    <p:ajax event="cellEdit" update="urlTable" immediate="true" process="@this"/>
    <p:column>
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{url}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{url}" style="width:96%" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

The problem is that each time I wrote a new value inside the cell it is not updating it. Lets say I have a cell with text "Hello" when I edit it to lets say "World" and press enter, it is not updating the value. requirementsDocuments is List with strings.

Comment: You still need to set the listener attribute of the ajax tag. The ajax will not automatically try to change url on the server unless you add a listener method on your managed bean and reference it via ajax.

Comment: try to remove `ìmmediat + process` , does your dataTable inside a form ?